# settimeout javascript doesn't function properly?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using the following code in order to display some texts to the users.

basically what I need to show is:

1
2
3
4

but this code shows,

1
4

here is the code:

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "1";
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "2";
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "3";
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "4";
    }, 4000);
    };
    </script>


<p id="p"></p>

<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" />
```

does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to downvote this because its quite obvious just by reading the code what the issue is. This is the danger of not being DRY, and copy and pasting code

Comment: Code works perfectly. Your implementation is wrong. You change `'p'` 3 times in one milisecond to 2, 3, 4

Comment: I love questions with titles like this that blame the language instead of the code writer.

Comment: All the setTimeout calls are started at roughly the same time. So the ones that prints 2 and 3 are executed, but at the same time as the one that prints 4.

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE, well, thanks for downvoting and keeping the "hidden secret" to yourself whilst others simply told me where i was going wrong!

Comment: @user3454730 sorry didnt mean to seem like keeping secrets, I already upvoted govind's answer so didnt feel it necessary to post an answer :) I just suspect you didnt even read your own code before asking what was wrong. Anyway, you have the right answer now!

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE, I replied to govind's answer. you might want to read that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "2";
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "3";
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "4";
}, 4000);
};
```

are editing the same element
so you see only the result of the last operation: 4

---

**The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.**
and in your case the time is same, so all executed at same time.

set some interval between them.

Comment: the reason I was confused was because i thought `setTimeout` was like `sleep()` function in PHP. I will accept this as the answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: Read manual before comparing fuctions from 2 different languages please.

Comment: @user3454730 The clue is the asynchronous callback. If the call to setTimeout was synchronous like PHP's sleep then you wouldn't need a callback. The next statement in the same scope would be adequate. And as Ultra says, you shouldn't make assumptions about the behaviour of this language based on a completely unrelated experience

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE, am I the only one who makes mistake!? I'm sure it is not set in stone and anyone can make assumptions on whatever they want and if they are wrong then they are simply wrong! I just don't understand why people are so hungry for downvoting others!! it is beyond me. out and over.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` doesn't calculate time from the finishing of previous `setTimeout`, but from the time the `setTimeout` statement was executed.

So, all the `setTimeout` statements with `2`, `3` and `4` are beginning to wait 4 seconds almost at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You  are editing the same element in quick succession, if you set different values for setTimeout, say 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, you would see the text change from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4, with a 1s interval (roughly) between each change.